# Get stripe customer data from stripe api customer array in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to get customer data from stripe api response data array. I want to get customer's address city, address_country etc. from this array

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
$stripe = \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

$profile = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(
  'cus_HTc4khEP1uaJZz',
  []
);
```

and output for this is below

```
[sources] => Stripe\Collection Object
        (
            [object] => list
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Stripe\Card Object
                        (
                            [id] => card_1GuepyIxhSBRY0yWSdkzFvIg
                            [object] => card
                            [address_city] => any
                            [address_country] => United States
                            [address_line1] => 343 ave
                            [address_line1_check] => pass
                            [address_line2] => 
                            [address_state] => OH
                            [address_zip] => 43343
                            [address_zip_check] => pass
                            [brand] => Visa
                            [country] => US
                            [customer] => cus_HTc4khEP1uaJZz
                            [cvc_check] => pass
                            [dynamic_last4] => 
                            [exp_month] => 1
                            [exp_year] => 2021
                            [fingerprint] => dEcJeuIvzniQcadl
                            [funding] => credit
                            [last4] => 4242
                            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                (
                                )

                            [name] => jack Smith
                            [tokenization_method] => 
                        )

                )
```

How to get each each element from this array.

```
Example :

echo $data[0]['address_country'];
```

Comment: `$profile->sources->data[0]->address_country`


This should do the trick, then similarly for the rest of the attributes. 

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you v3nkman ! It worked.